# Django: How to Sum By Range_Date

Tags: django, django-views

Filter with the date and find the sum of the range, not the total of all the objects,example, from January 1 until January 2 or from February 1 to February 20, each range.

```
This is my code:


def orecerca(request):
qs = Ore.objects.filter(user=request.user)
sum = Ore.objects.filter(user=request.user).aggregate(totals=(Sum('oret')))
nomecognome = request.GET.get('nomecognome')
date_min = request.GET.get('date_min')
date_max = request.GET.get('date_max')


if is_valid_queryparam(nomecognome):
    qs = qs.filter(nomecognome=nomecognome)

if is_valid_queryparam(date_min):
    qs = qs.filter(data__gte=date_min) 

if is_valid_queryparam(date_max): 
    qs = qs.filter(data__lte=date_max)

context = {
    'ore': qs,
    'sum': sum,
    } 
return render(request, "guarda.html", context,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can postpone aggregating until you constructed the filtered queryset, like:

```
def orecerca(request):
    qs = Ore.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    nomecognome = request.GET.get('nomecognome')
    date_min = request.GET.get('date_min')
    date_max = request.GET.get('date_max')

    if is_valid_queryparam(nomecognome):
        qs = qs.filter(nomecognome=nomecognome)

    if is_valid_queryparam(date_min):
        qs = qs.filter(data__gte=date_min) 

    if is_valid_queryparam(date_max): 
        qs = qs.filter(data__lte=date_max)

    total = qs.aggregate(totals=(Sum('oret')))

    context = {
        'ore': qs,
        'sum': total,
    } 
    return render(request, "guarda.html", context,)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: It might be helpful to note that you can also filter by a date_range instead of doing two separate filters.  `qs = qs.filter(date__range=(date_min, date_max))`

Comment: @B.Adler: yes, but a potential problem here is that the `date_min` might be defined, whereas `date_max` might not be defined.